# What are some loanwords in Latin where there is no native synonym?

Tags: vocabulary, synonyms

My question about a [Latin word for "tattoo"](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/17496/is-there-a-noun-for-a-tattoo) prompted some surprise in me that the Romans didn't borrow a word for tattoo. One would think that some group of people they interacted with who practiced tattooing had their own word for the tattoo itself. Perhaps it happened regionally but was lost or not recorded.

This got me wondering further, what are some examples of loanwords in Latin where there is no single, native Latin word with a similar meaning? In English, we see this with the German loanwords *zeitgeist* or *bildungsroman*.

Comment: [This answer](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/15969/81) links to a study on this subject, including words from various languages.

Comment: Do you still intend to exclude the Greek words?

Comment: No, Greek words are also welcome.

Comment: You'll get a whole bunch with Greek. Mostly technical words.